# sql insert into table with select case values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For some reason I am having trouble with this statement

```
Insert into TblStuff
(FullName,Address,City,Zip)

Select
Case
When Middle is Null Then Fname + LName as FullName,
Else Fname +' ' + Middle + ' '+ Lname as FullName,
End
Case
When Address2 is Null Then Address1 as Address,
else Address1 +', ' + Address2 as  Address,
End
City as City,
Zip as Zip
from tblImport
```

I am getting the incorrect syntax near keyword 'as'

Edited to add to this question, let me know if I need to add new post or not.

I know the below is little different statement, but  can you make a case statement something similar to below?  Does the below statment even make sense?

```
Insert into TblStuff
    (NickName,FirstName,MiddleName,Suffix)

    Case when FirstName IS NULL then 
        NickName as Nickname,
        IsNULL(FirstName,'''') as FirstName,
        IsNULL(MiddelName,'''') as MiddleName,
        IsNULL(NameSuffix,'''') as Suffix,
    Else
        IsNull(NickName2,'''') as NickName,
        IsNULL(FirstName,'''') as FirstName,
        IsNULL(MiddelName,'''') as Middlename,
        Case when NameSuffix2 is NULL then
            IsNULL(NameSuffix,'''')as suffix,
        Else
            IsNULL(NameSuffix,'''') + '''', '''' + IsNULL(NameSuffix2,'''') as suffix,
        End
    End
From tblImport
```

Comment: All the answers works, thanks a lot guys!  I have one more question, I am not sure if I need to make a new post or just ask within this post or not, but here goes.  Say in the case statement I was something like this work

Answer (score 23):

You need commas after `end` finishing the case statement.  And, the "as" goes after the `case` statement, not inside it:

```
Insert into TblStuff(FullName, Address, City, Zip)
    Select (Case When Middle is Null Then Fname + LName
                 Else Fname +' ' + Middle + ' '+ Lname
            End)  as FullName,
           (Case When Address2 is Null Then Address1
                 else Address1 +', ' + Address2
            End)  as  Address,
           City as City,
           Zip as Zip
    from tblImport
```

Answer (score 9):

You have the alias inside of the case, it needs to be outside of the `END`:

```
Insert into TblStuff (FullName,Address,City,Zip)
Select
  Case
    When Middle is Null 
    Then Fname + LName
    Else Fname +' ' + Middle + ' '+ Lname
  End as FullName,
  Case
    When Address2 is Null Then Address1
    else Address1 +', ' + Address2 
  End as  Address,
  City as City,
  Zip as Zip
from tblImport
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of CASE expression. Because result of concatenating anything to NULL, even itself, is always NULL

```
INSERT TblStuff(FullName,Address,City,Zip)
SELECT COALESCE(Fname + ' ' + Middle + ' ' + Lname, Fname + LName) AS FullName,
       COALESCE(Address1 + ', ' + Address2, Address1) AS Address, City, Zip
FROM tblImport
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5af31/3)

Comment: That looks likes what I was trying to accomplish, I am not sure how to wrap my head around this logic yet, but it works :)  Thanks.  I would vote your answer, but I am not at 15 yet.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to read these posts: How does accepting an answer work?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I know how to accept answers, but what if I used bits and parts of each post to make my solution?

Answer (score 0):

If FName and LName contain NULL values, then you will need special handling to avoid unnecessary extra preceeding, trailing, and middle spaces.  Also, if Address1 contains NULL values, then you need to have special handling to prevent adding unnecessary ', ' at the beginning of your address string.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use CONCAT (NULLs are automatically treated as empty strings) and IIF:

```
INSERT INTO TblStuff (FullName, Address, City, Zip)
SELECT FullName = REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(FName, ' ', Middle, ' ', LName))), '  ', ' ')
    , Address = CONCAT(Address1, IIF(Address2 IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(', ', Address2), ''))
    , City
    , Zip
FROM tblImport (NOLOCK);
```

Otherwise, this will work:

```
INSERT INTO TblStuff (FullName, Address, City, Zip)
SELECT FullName = REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(FName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(Middle, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(LName, ''))), '  ', ' ')
    , Address = ISNULL(Address1, '') + CASE
        WHEN Address2 IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + Address2
        ELSE '' END
    , City
    , Zip
FROM tblImport (NOLOCK);
```