# SQL INSERT with conditional statement IF THEN ELSE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I am trying to MERGE values from one table to another. One of the values is a conditional value, but it looks like I am not getting the syntax correctly. Initially, I was using an IF-THEN-ELSE statement but was advise to use a CASE statement instead.

Here is the gist the syntax that is failing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeMerge
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE INTO Employee AS t1  
    USING 
        (SELECT 
               EmployeeName,
               Zip,
               UpdateDate 
        FROM table2) AS t2
        ON (t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID)
    WHEN MATCHED AND t2.UpdatedDate > t1.UpdatedDate THEN 
        UPDATE 
        SET 
            t1.EmployeeName = s.EmployeeName, 
            t1.Zip =
                (CASE 
                    WHEN t2.ZipExt IS NULL OR t2.ZipExt = '' THEN t2.Zip 
                    ELSE (t2.Zip + '-' + t2.ZipExt)
                END),
            t1.UpdatedDate = t2.UpdateDate
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (EmployeeName,  
            Zip,  
            ModDate)
        VALUES 
            (t2.Name, 
            (CASE 
                WHEN t2.ZipExt IS NULL OR t2.ZipExt = '' THEN t2.Zip 
                ELSE (t2.Zip + '-' + t2.Zip_Ext)
            END),
            t2.UpdatedDate)
    OUTPUT 
        deleted.*, 
        $action, 
        inserted.* 
END; **-- A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)**
GO
```

This MERGE statement works just fine if I do not implement the condition, i.e. simply set the t1.Zip = t2.Zip, but of course, this is avoiding the t2.ZipExt field.

Comment: You must use case switch [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820405/sql-insert-into-table-with-select-case-values)

Comment: Get rid of the if and use a case. Post the full SQL if you want more specifics   :)

Comment: @Max, I have updated my SQL statement, please reference, thanks!

Comment: @SpectralGhost, I have updated my SQL statement, please reference, thanks!

Comment: ok we resolved the original issue. What problem are you seeing now?

Comment: Shouldn't the plus signs ('+') in the following `ELSE (t2.Zip + '-' + t2.Zip_Ext)` be the double bars ('||') for concantenation?

Comment: @user118190 What SQL are you using? Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @SpectralGhost, yes SQL Server 2012. It looks like my other tags got removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)

You haven't terminated the MERGE with a semicolon. You have terminated BEGIN-END. Move the semicolon.

Comment: I just figured it out myself and as I loaded SO to update my thread, I noticed your answer. I can't I was overseeing such simple issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I never really cared for the merge command. There are times where I can see using it, but for the most part, it's more complicated than I like my SQL.

```
UPDATE e
SET     e.EmployeeName=t1.EmployeeName
    ,   e.Zip=CASE 
                WHEN t1.ZipExt IS NULL OR t1.ZipExt = '' THEN t1.Zip 
                ELSE (t1.Zip + '-' + t1.ZipExt)
            END
    ,   e.UpdatedDate=t1.UpdatedDate
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Table t1 ON e.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
WHERE t1.UpdatedDate > e.UpdatedDate

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeName,Zip,UpdatedDate)
    SELECT
            t1.EmployeeName
        ,   t1.Zip=CASE 
                WHEN t1.ZipExt IS NULL OR t1.ZipExt = '' THEN t1.Zip 
                ELSE (t1.Zip + '-' + t1.ZipExt)
            END
        ,   t1.UpdatedDate
    FROM Table t1
    LEFT JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
    WHERE e.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Comment: I changed my MERGE into an UPDATE and INSERT statement as you have and I am still getting a syntax error of "Incorrect syntax near '='." within the INSERT statement right in between t1.Zip and CASE. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The end parens needed removed as I had removed the front parens

Comment: Oh, almost forgot, I also changed your code by what seems like two extra right parentheses at the end of the CASE statements, i.e. after the END keyword. Would you agree?